# What does "kite" mean in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know the term kite from WoW, there it means letting the enemey move around and prevent it from dealing damage.

Yesterday, someone in LoL said:
"omfg udyr kite freakin ezreal!"

I dont get this, I mean you cant kite a 
range based damage dealer and anyway, its another online player not an NPC so Id like to know what kite means in LoL?

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that you cannot kite another player?

If another (N)PC keeps following and/or primarily targeting you based on actions from your side, I think that qualifies for kiting! From my understanding it has nothing to do with doing it with another player or non player character.

Comment: Well as Udyr you have a proper amount of HP, so who would focus Udyr and run after him during a teamfight? 2nd I dont think that kiting a range damage based champ works since he doesnt really have to walk close up to you

Comment: @RandomDisplayName but even a ranged DD needs to keep you in range, so I stand by my definition.

Comment: You can kite any character that has a skillshot. Ezreal has literally all the skill shots.